# how to convert milli seconds to time android

Tags: android

I have an application which reads incoming and outgoing SMS. Logcat shows all variable correctly except the date string. its always something like  this. 1254785965412. Below is my code, how can I change this millisecond time to a readable format like 2:50 PM or 25 June 14:50.

```
Uri smsURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(smsURI, new String[]{"address", "date", "body", "type"}, null, null, null);
            String[] columns = new String[]{"address", "date", "body", "type"};
            c.moveToNext();
            String recipient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
            String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            Log.d("DetectOutgoingSMS", recipient + " , " + date + " , " + message + " , " +type);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a new `Date` object with the MS time.

```
long dateMs = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
Date date = new Date(dateMs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Then you can either get the whole date as a string:

```
String dateString = date.toString();
```

Or a just portion of the date

```
int dateInt = date.getHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormat to control the format of your date or to get formats that make sense for different locales....

```
Date messageDate = new Date(milliseconds);
DataFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
String localeAwareReadableDate = df.format(messageDate);
```

On a device set to US English will be formatted like

```
Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM
```